# How to prove that you can ignore the complex coefficient when finding periods in Mandelbrot Set?

Tags: analysis, bifurcation

So essentially, I am under the impression that if any Ai + B has a period of *k*, then B will have a period of *k* as well. For example, -0.2i - 0.5 has a period of 1, hence, -0.5 has a period of 1. Similarly, 0.1i - 1.0 has a period of 2, and -1.0 has a period of 2. How do I prove this correspondence?

Edit: or follow up to this, how do I prove that it only bifurcates (ie. the bifurcation parameter) at a real value?

[image: Mandelbrot Set]

Comment: Can you please clarify the terms? What does “Ai + B has a period of k” mean? I *assume* that you mean something like “the polynomial $z^2+Ai+B$ has an periodic point with period $k$”. And “ignore the complex coefficient” means “take the real part only”? –  I also assume that your conjecture is wrong, e.g. if you choose $Ai+B$ in the main cardiod such that $B$ is  outside of it.

Comment: I mean if we look at the [bifurcation diagram of the Mandelbrot Set](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Logistic_Map_Bifurcations_Underneath_Mandelbrot_Set.gif/220px-Logistic_Map_Bifurcations_Underneath_Mandelbrot_Set.gif), it is the real axis that matters in bifurcations. I was just wondering why this is the case.

Comment: Consider $A=0.2$ and $B=0.26$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for pointing that out! Follow up on my original, is there any particular reason why period bifurcations only occur at real values?